# How to compare exported variable with its value

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am doing this

```
export CORELOCKR_LIB=MINI_RIP
if [ $CORELOCKR_LIB -eq "MINI_RIP" ]
then
    export RIP_SSL_LITE_CRYPTO_USE_TM_FLAG=0
elif
    export RIP_SSL_LITE_CRYPTO_USE_TM_FLAG=1
fi
```

I am getting error such as ***missing seperator.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: the `elif` should contain a condition, doesn't it?

Comment: `else` instead of `elif`? or `elif` with a condition?

Comment: `-eq` is limited to integer comparison.  for string `==`

Comment: Use `=` with `[`, not `==`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with comparisons or exported variables; it's just a syntax error in your `if` statement.